# Web scraping with beautifulsoup not finding anything

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to scrape coinmarketcap.com just to get an update of a certain currency price, also just to learn how to web scrape. I'm still a beginner and can't figure out where I'm going wrong, because whenever I try to run it, it just tells me there are none. Although I know that line does exist. Any help is appreciated!

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/electroneum/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('data-currency-price data-usd=')
print (price)
```

Comment: you're not using `find` properly. read the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class attribute to get the value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/electroneum/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span' ,attrs={"class" : "h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price__value"})
print (price.text)
```

Output :

```
0.006778
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be doing alot of this consider doing a single call using the [official API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide) and get all the prices. Then extract what you want. The following is from the site with an amendment by me to show the desired value for electroneum. The API guidance shows how to retrieve [one at a time](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyMarketpairsLatest) as well, though that requires a higher plan than the basic.

```
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
parameters = {
      'start': '1',
      'limit': '5000',
      'convert': 'USD',
  }
headers = {
      'Accepts': 'application/json',
      'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'yourKey',
  }

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

try:
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    # print(response.text)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(data['data'][64]['quote']['USD']['price'])
except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
    print(e)
```

You can always deploy a loop and check against a desired list e.g.

```
interested = ['Electroneum','Ethereum']
for item in data['data']:
    if item['name'] in interested:
        print(item)
```

---

For your current example:

You can use an attribute selector for `data-currency-value`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/electroneum/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('[data-currency-value]').text
```

---

Comment: This should be more efficient if doing a lot of this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/electroneum/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find("span", id="quote_price").get('data-usd')
print (price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to be more specific in how you want to FIND the item.

you currently are using `soup.find('')` I am not sure what you have put inside this as you wrote data-currency-price data-usd=
Is that an ID a class name?

why not try finding the item using an ID.

```
soup.find(id="link3")
```

or find by tag

```
soup.find("relevant tag name like div or a")
```

or something like this

```
find_this = soup.find("a", id="ID HERE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/electroneum/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
x=soup(id="quote_price").text
print (x)
```

Look for ID better,or search through `soup.find_all(text="data-currency-price data-usd")[1].text`