# Problem getting Strings from Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda

so here is my code I'm trying to get working

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://digitalcoinprice.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'coin_currency_name'}):
    title = link.string
    print(title)
```

my ultimate goal is to create a web crawler that will log the information of the top 100 cryptocurrencies every 5 minutes. I'd like to work this problem out but am struggling with this hurdle. when I run

```
python wcrawl.py
```

all it does is moves to where I can type a new command.... Sorry I'm not knowledgeable enough on the topic to give any more detail, I have been using python a whole 12 hours now.

just some more info:

Windows 10
inside Anaconda CMD Prompt
Python 3.7.2

Comment: It moves to where you can type, I think you mean your script doesn't output anything and exit. In another word, soup didn't find the text you gave. Just try some very obvious tab, e.g.: <head> or sth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to find 'span' tag instead 'a' tag.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://digitalcoinprice.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'coin_currency_name'}):
    title = link.string
    print(title)
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Now I'm working on getting this information into a csv file.... and that's a whole new challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and read_html for this

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://digitalcoinprice.com/')
print(tables[0])
```

If doing a lot consider also using an [API method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54931437/6241235)